# Git Commands - Local Repository vs. Remote Repository

Tags: git, repository

What are the different commands that can be used with only remote Git repository but cannot be used on local Git repository and vice-versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Git commands (almost all of them actually) are made to be used with local repositories only, to minimize latencies.

Some of them work with remote repositories *as well as* local ones:

```
git clone
git pull
git push
git fetch
git ls-remote
git remote prune/update
```

I don't have on the top of my head a git command which would work exclusively with a remote one, if by remote you mean "outside of your local computer".
Each of the aforementioned command works with a "remote" repository which can be right there, on your hard drive.
Arguably, the [`git remote-helpers`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote-helpers) are used to communicate with repositories generally hosted outside your local computer though.

Comment: `git remote prune/update`; *formally* these are different commands from `git fetch` :-)